# Default login screen missing, how to revert?

Tags: gnome, 13.10, kde, lightdm, login-screen

I installed some KDE stuff by mistake. After removing it, my login screen now is quite different; has a white background and the user icons+input appear in the centre.

[note that I have tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`; amongst other things]

How do I revert back to the default Ubuntu 13.10 x64 desktop one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to edit your `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file, and change this line

```
greeter-session=lightdm-kde-greeter
```

to this one

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

Or simply reconfiguring the greeter (not the Desktop Manager) might work also:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unity-greeter
```

Comment: In `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` I changed `greeter-session`; should I change: `user-session=kde-plasma` also? - If so, to what?

Comment: (also I wasn't testing out a new desktop environment, I was installing some editor or IDE IIRC; which had a bunch of deps)

Comment: @AT: Oh, someone kinda boosted up my answer. I only wrote ca. the last 10 lines of the answer. Changing the greeter-session will give you back your login screen. (Did it work?) The user-session is just the default graphic session which loads after you login. You can change it back to `ubuntu` if you don't want KDE as default, but you can always change the user-session on the login screen also if you want to switch. (regarding the installation, next time you might want to install with `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends PACKAGENAME` )

Comment: @NikTh I did a rollback because your edit is added too much new information to my answer, which changed my answer too much. Please consider adding a different answer, not an edit if you have that much more to add. (Even if our answers will overlap in some points.)

Comment: @falconer In Ubuntu 14.04, I installed (and removed) `xubuntu-desktop`, and that has taken away the Unity greeter. There's no file of the sort you mention in your answer (`lightdm.conf`). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to [falconer](https://askubuntu.com/users/221281/falconer) answer you can change 
`greeter-session=unity-greeter`
In my case (ubuntu 16.04 LTS), config is located in:
`/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`
[useful link about login screens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797845/how-do-i-change-the-login-screen-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score -1):

For me

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

did solve the issue

Comment: It will solve it, but this can damage things...