# unity-greeter: missing indicators on login screen after logout

Tags: lightdm, unity-greeter

Just installed Ubuntu 16.04.
It uses lightdm and unity-greeter.

If only one user is logged in (Unity session), the login screen does not look fine after logout, these indicators are missing: power, sound, keyboard …

Is it a bug ?

The only thing there is in the top right corner is 'onscreen keyboard' menu.

In a console (ctrl-alt-F1), restarting lightdm brings the indicators back.

After a machine reboot on the other hand, the login screen has everything.

Comment: I see this too, also the wallpaper doesn't show up like it should for me (like in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797845)). For me, if I lock the screen and get the unity-greeter then it works fine, but if I log out or switch user then I get LightDM which is broken as you describe.

Comment: I have filed a bug report for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1608164

Comment: Also:  I get a black screen when I try to get a tty via Ctrl-alt-F1..F6 -- I think it still works though when I type a login and password in the dark.

Comment: I believe that the login screen is on tty7, i.e. Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Comment: Yes the login screen is on tty7. But yesterday my tty1 to tty6 were black screens. I don't know if it is related to the login screen bug or if it is a completely different one. Today after a system restart, they are normal however.

Comment: I received the lightdm update (1.18.2-0ubuntu2) which seems to solve the missing indicators problem on the login screen. But the blank ttys come back. Looks like there may be another bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug has been confirmed, in [this Launchpad tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1605117). There is a fix committed to the `lightdm` package, version 1.18.2-0ubuntu2.

It's currently in the proposed repo for Xenial (16.04) - I've enabled the proposed repo from the [instructions here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed) and installed the updated version. (I also followed the selective upgrades instructions, so that only packages I choose update to the proposed versions.)

If you don't want to play around with the proposed repository, that's OK - the updated package should make its way into the normal updates soon enough.