# Changing the background of the login screen changes the design of the login screen

Tags: 16.04, login, lightdm, login-screen

In 16.04, to change the background of the login screen, I followed the accepted answer at [How do I change the login screen in Ubuntu 16.04+?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797845/how-do-i-change-the-login-screen-in-ubuntu-16-04), however, when I selected the new background, the theme of the background changed as in:

1) The text box for the password is now in the centre of the screen (instead of the middle-left).

2) The look of the login prompt is now changed to old-style rectangular gray background

3) The login grid has disappeared.

I undid all the changes, however even the original look and feel of the login prompt is totally gone.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH4Ob.png) is how it looks now:

Also, the lock screen has had no effect to these changes and remains original.

How do I get the login back to its original look and feel, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw3Ea.png)?

I had a look at all the available answers, but all of them talk about previous versions of Ubuntu (not 16.04) and they dont work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Shubhanga.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. The problem is with `lightdm` in the sense that it changes the design of the login screen into the old layout. I believe the correct method was to just follow the answer at [How do I change the login screen in Ubuntu 16.04+?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797845/how-do-i-change-the-login-screen-in-ubuntu-16-04) and follow the `unity-greeter` settings and not install `lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings`.

Also, once `unity-greeter` has been suitably configured, the following command had to be executed in the terminal.

```
sudo apt purge lightdm-gtk-greeter lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings
```