# How to change lock screen background and keep the wallpaper unchanged

Tags: unity, lock-screen, desktop-background

I am on Ubuntu 16 and I want to change the lock screen background. I don't want by wallpaper to be changed.

I have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/868899/377375) but it only changes the login screen wallpaper. I want the changes to reflect each time I lock the screen with <kbd>Home</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try the second answer in the link or just the first one?